# Integrating a gaussian over a very long interval

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I want to integrate a Gaussian function over a very large interval. I chose spicy.integrate.quad function for the integration. The function seems to work only when I select a small enough interval. When I use the codes below,

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

def func(x, mean, sigma):
    return 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma) * exp(-1/2*((x-mean)/sigma)**2) 

print(quad(func, 0, 1e+31, args=(1e+29, 1e+28))[0]) # case 1
print(quad(func, 0, 1e+32, args=(1e+29, 1e+28))[0]) # case 2
print(quad(func, 0, 1e+33, args=(1e+29, 1e+28))[0]) # case 3
print(quad(func, 1e+25, 1e+33, args=(1e+29, 1e+28))[0]) # case 4
```

then the followings are printed.

```
1.0
1.0000000000000004
0.0
0.0
```

To obtain a reasonable result, I had to try and change the lower/upper bounds of the integral several times and empirically determine it to [0, 1e+32]. This seems risky to me, as when the mean and sigma of the gaussian function changes, then I always have to try different bounds.

Is there a clear way to integrate the function from 0 to 1e+50 without bothering with bounds? If not, how do you expect from beginning which bounds would give non-zero value?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179778/scipy-quad-uses-only-1-subdivision-and-gives-wrong-result

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193045/why-does-integrate-quadlambda-x-xexp-x2-2-sqrt2pi-0-0-100000-give-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't.

On this long interval, the region where the gaussian is non-zero is tiny, and the adaptive procedure which works under the hood of integrate.quad fails to see it. And so would pretty much any adaptive routine, unless by chance.

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

[image]

and the CDF of a normal random variable is known as `ϕ(x)` as it can not be expressed by an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). So take `ϕ((b-m)/s) - ϕ((a-m)/s)`. Also note that `ϕ(x) = 1/2(1 + erf(x/sqrt(2)))` so you need not call `.quad` to actually perform an integration and may have better luck with [`erf`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.erf) from `scipy`.

```
from scipy.special import erf

def prob(mu, sigma, a, b):
    phi = lambda x: 1/2*(1 + erf((x - mu)/(sigma*np.sqrt(2))))
    return phi(b) - phi(a)
```

This may give more accurate results (it does than the above)

```
>>> print(prob(0, 1e+31, 0, 1e+50))
0.5
>>> print(prob(0, 1e+32, 1e+28, 1e+29))
0.000359047985937333
>>> print(prob(0, 1e+33, 1e+28, 1e+29))
3.5904805169684195e-05
>>> print(prob(1e+25, 1e+33, 1e+28, 1e+29))
3.590480516979522e-05
```

and avoid the intense [`floating point`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) error you are experiencing. However, the regions you integrate are so small in area that you may still see `0`.